# Type of matrix output in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I need count of customers  who got subscribed to channels.

```
Where channel = telugu and channel = hindi

Where channel = telugu and channel = English 

Where channel = hindi and channel = English
```

Comment: [Try using count](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/count-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: your `WHERE` clause will not work. There will not be a match for `Where channel = telugu and channel = hindi`. You probably wants a `OR`

Answer (score 0):

I think I know what you're going for... Customers can have multiple channels and you're interested in counting customers who have specific combinations of channels.
If that is correct AND your combinations all have the same number of elements, you can use something like the following.

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#channel_pairs', 'U') IS NOT NULL 
BEGIN DROP TABLE #channel_pairs; END;

CREATE TABLE #channel_pairs (
    c1 varchar(20) NOT NULL,
    c2 varchar(20) NOT null
    );
INSERT #channel_pairs (c1, c2) VALUES ('telugu', 'hindi'), ('telugu', 'English'), ('hindi', 'English');

SELECT 
    channel_pair = cp.c1 + ', ' + cp.c2,
    cp_count = COUNT(1)
FROM
    dbo.customer_channel cc1
    JOIN dbo.customer_channel cc2
        ON cc1.customer_id = cc2.customer_id
    JOIN #channel_pairs cp
        ON cc1.channel = cp.c1
        AND cc2.channel = cp.c2;
```